# Creating a Sharepoint 2010 Solution in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to create Sharepoint 2010 solution in Visual Studio 2013.  I only have SP 2010 installed on this machine.  In Visual Studio 2012, I have the SP 2010 templates, but I don't have them in VS 2013.  When I try to create an empty Sharepoint solution, it tells me I don't have Sharepoint 2013 installed.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS 2013 only supports creating SharePoint 2013 solutions.  You must stick with VS2012 to create Sharepoing 2010 solutions.  You can open SharePoint 2010 solutions in VS 2013.  This does have to do with having each version of SharePoint installed on your machine to properly test with.

Here is a link to the VS 2013 compatibility matrix:

[VS 2013 Compatibility Matrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh266747%28v=vs.120%29.aspx)

Comment: I can't open my SP 2010 solutions in VS 2013.  Tells me the Microsoft Excahnge Service cannot be found and all of my solution packages are empty (says it can't find the features).  It is a hot mess.

Comment: Usually when you open a solution and VS can't find something due to an error it will display your solution in the Solution Explorer as empty.  If you can fix your Exchange Service issue, I would think your solution will display properly.

Answer (score 6):

I have Visual Studio 2013 Premium and I can create/deploy/debug SharePoint 2010 solutions. I've tested this on my laptop that has SharePoint 2010 installed with Visual Studio 2013

Comment: That's true. The issue was in early version of Visual Studio 2013. Now it's gone. Also double-checked recently.

Comment: I've also checked creating/opening SharePoint 2010 projects in Visual Studio 2015 Professional and it works fine. The only thing to consider is that once the project is opened it's migrated to `Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00` and it cannot be opened in Visual Studio 2010 afterwards.